# Favorites in Internet Explorer won't take me to location

Tags: bookmarks, internet-explorer-9

Specs:
Windows 7 x64
IE 9 (using x86 version)

For some reason, whenever I click on a .url file, it will not take me to the destination. It doesn't even open a blank tab. It doesn't do anything. All of the favorites now have a generic globe icon. (Not sure what this implies, if anything at all.)

In an attempt to resolve this issue I have done the following:

- Ran a virus scan (clean)
- Ran a malware scan (clean)
- Check default program for .url (Set to IE)
- Checked the favorites registry entry (All set)
- Reset my IE settings (Did not delete personal info)
- Created new favorite files (New ones were just as broken)
- "Uninstalled" and reinstalled IE
- Ran Windows Updates (None for IE, but did update some stuff anyways)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this was unanswered from a past life. I ended up rebuilding my machine. Clean install of OS. A bit of a drastic solution, but that is what worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one on for size. I realise it's aimed at XP but it's worth a try.

> Recently I've had several Windows XP computers that all of the sudden
>   have their Internet Explorer Favorites or their Internet Shortcuts
>   stop working. You see all of the Favorites however when you click on
>   them IE does nothing.
>
> Try this out if this is what you are seeing:
>
> - Open Registry Editor and navigate to:
> - HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShor­tcut
> - Backup this key and save as REG file.
> - Now delete 'InternetShortcut' key.
> - Open Internet Explorer, Tools, Internet Options, Programs
> - Choose "Reset Web Settings"
> - The URL association should be rebuilt now.

Source: http://thetazblog.taznetworks.com/2005/04/internet-explorer-favorites-or.html

Comment: Thanks for the article, but sadly it did not work for me. What a great find though!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the Microsoft community, try [resetting Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings#ie=ie-11):

> 1. Close all Internet Explorer windows. Select the Tools  button [or Control Panel > Network and Internet], and then select Internet options.
> 2. Select the Advanced tab, and then select Reset.
> 3. In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, select Reset.
> 4. When Internet Explorer finishes applying default settings, select Close, and then select OK. Restart your PC to apply changes.

These steps resolved the same issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you describe *how* to reset those settings in your answer here? :)

Comment: @bertieb Sure, just did.